# Touch pad freez in linux

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad

I'm using **Linux mint 17.2 Rafaela**.

My touch pad froze suddenly after I restarted the system. The issue is still there even after I boot up the pc.

I also tried to change the setting using `gpointing` application, but the issue still persists.

Is there any permanent solution for this issue? .

I found some temporary solution using `modprobe' (Used ; 'sudo modprobe -r psmouse' & 'sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps') to make the cursor work but it is not an effective solution.

Comment: `modprobe` what? Please provide some more details

Comment: Used ; 'sudo modprobe -r psmouse' & 'sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps'